# ERROR: Cell Contents indices must be greater than 0

Tags: matlab

Hi I keep getting  this error for the following code:

p1 is an array of cells 
pLeft,pRight,pUp,pDown are just p1 rotated in a direction

```
for m =randperm(N^2);

 format long 
 guess= rand;
 zz=[4,5,6,7];
 zzz={pLeft{m},pRight{m},pUp{m},pDown{m}};
 swapmap=containers.Map(zz,zzz);
 zzzz={mod(m-N,N^2),mod(m+N,N^2),mod(m-1,N^2),mod(m+1,N^2)};
 swapmap2=containers.Map(zz,zzzz);
 direction=randperm(4)+3;


   if  p1{m}(direction(1))>guess
    [p1{m}, swapmap(direction(1))] = deal(swapmap(direction(1)),p1{m});
     p1{swapmap2(direction(1))}=swapmap(direction(1));    
  end
   if  p1{m}(direction(2))>guess
    [p1{m},swapmap(direction(2))] = deal(swapmap(direction(2)),p1{m});
     p1{swapmap2(direction(2))}=swapmap(direction(2));   
   end
    if  p1{m}(direction(3))>guess
     [p1{m}, swapmap(direction(3))] = deal(swapmap(direction(3)),p1{m});
     p1{swapmap2(direction(3))}=swapmap(direction(3));   
    end
    if  p1{m}(direction(4))>guess
     [p1{m},swapmap(direction(4))] = deal(swapmap(direction(4)),p1{m});
      p1{swapmap2(direction(4))}=swapmap(direction(4));   
    end
```

end

I get the following error

```
Cell contents indices must be greater than 0

  Error in test3 (line 114)
    p1{swapmap2(direction(2))}=swapmap(direction(2));
```

Comment: That means `swapmap2(direction(2))` is outputting either 0 or a negative number.  We can't figure out what's wrong with your code unless we see the contents of `swapmap2`.  BTW, please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - The current state of your code, no one can run it to figure out what the true error is.

Comment: Thank you from you comment, I'm sorry its a very long piece. swapmap2 gives an index of p1 eg   p1{mod(m-N,N^2)}. I have read that it may be to so with the fact that i have used a matlab built in function mod as a variable?

Comment: It looks like both the expression `mod(m-N,N^2)` and `mod(m-1,N^2)` will evaluate to zero at some point, which would lead to a bad index in your cell arrays.

Comment: Thank you gariepy I can't believe I didn't notice this! Thanks